# Email open-rate optimization

Tags: machine-learning, classification, modeling, decision-theory, marketing

I am trying to maximize open rates of emails by selecting between two subject headlines {h1, h2} for a marketing campaing. The hypothesis is that different customers react to different headlines.

During a data collection phase, emails were sent to a pool of customers, where the headline was selected randomly from {h1, h2}. Each customer was sent only a single email, so *we do not know how she would have reacted to the other headline*.

I built a pair of predictors P(open; customer_i, h1), P(open; customer_i, h2) by calibrating the response of two respective classifiers. One classifier was trained with a subset of the customers that received h1, and the other classifier with the those that received h2.

The decision logic is to use h1 if the predicted probability of opening the email is larger for h1 than for h2.

Is it possible to obtain an estimate of the open rate before sending the next batch of emails? If not, which measure could I use to select from multiple pairs pairs of predictors?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this then?

Comment: No, sorry, I never got to really work got to actually work on solving this issue.

Comment: I tried to achieve the same by feeding polished and n-gram-ed subject lines to a train model with different algorithm with the number of actual opens to predict the quality of the subject, it has an accuracy of 29% but still not great results.

Comment: Yes, my impression is that it is hard too. What is the 29% exactly?

Comment: I used 100k records (Subject line,Number of opens/Total sends), 75k were used to train the model, 25k were predicted and the 29% of the 25k predicted a correct opens/sends).

Comment: Ok, but if that dataset is unbalanced (which it probably is), the 29% doesn't actually say much. Your algorithm is classifier may way too eager to say "open". Better look for AUC.

Comment: This is why I was looking for examples, this is my first ml experiment. What do you mean by unbalanced data? I have 10 classes: 0-10% open 10-20% etc...

Comment: You are trying to predict what percentage of people open the email? Why not predict if individual people will open the email? This seems like a weird use case.

Comment: Not sure I'm with you, how can I make prediction on individuals? I can only tell how people are likely to open it. (And I'm not after a binary answer, but rather the quality of the title).

Comment: If you don't have features of individuals, you are right, it would not make sense to classify individuals. When I was working on that problem, I had additional information about each address. But then what you want to do is a regression and not a classification. Strictly speaking though, you can create useful features just from the email addresses themselves, for instance using the domain or username.

Comment: I am indeed using regression as well (a colleague tried with classification and % buckets, but my experiment was with regression). At the stage of composition of the campaign, you don't have yet recipient informations. We would also use sender name-domain to understand if it is "open-friendly" but probably the subject is more relevant.